# rediagonalizing a diagonalized matrix with constant off-diagonals

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms

Hi Math StackExchange,

I have an application where I need to diagonalize a matrix repeatedly as its diagonal and off-diagonal elements fluctuate. I think that I can make a decent approximation for my application by replacing all the off-diagonal elements with constants and only allowing the diagonal elements to fluctuate. My question is: if I have already diagonalized the initial matrix (with the initial values of the diagonal elements and the chosen constant value of the off-diagonal elements), is there any mathematical shortcut that would allow me to obtain eigenvectors and eigenvalues (or good approximations thereof) for a new matrix with a new diagonal but same off-diagonal content without re-diagonalizing the matrix from the beginning at every step?

The matrix is, in general, dense, not diagonally dominant or anything like that.

Thank you!

poisonDartFrog